# Как определить что программа запущена в первый раз?

Tags: c#

Как определить что программа запущена в первый раз? Без создания папок или файлов настроек. Эти способы я знаю. Как определить чисто без всего этого? Может есть какой метод?

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/73891/discussion-on-question-by-------).

Answer (score 3):

Правильный путь для этого — `Settings` ([[1]](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/354982/10105), [[2]](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/466102/10105)).

Пропишите настройку типа `bool` в User Scope с именем `IsFirstRun` и значением `true`.

В коде программы, в начале, пропишите:

```
bool isFirstRun = Properties.Settings.Default.IsFirstRun;
if (isFirstRun)
{
    Properties.Settings.Default.IsFirstRun = false;
    Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
}
```

Всё!

---

Без использования настроек сделать это можно, но вам придётся по сути делать то же самое, только вручную. Не изобретайте велосипед.

---

Если вы хотите бороться против злонамеренного пользователя на его компьютере, считайте, что вы проиграли до начала битвы. Пользователь на своей машине может вообще всё. Он может запустить ваш код под отладчиком и обратить вашу логику проверок. Он может запустить вас в виртуальной машине. Он может декомпилировать ваш код, убрать проверки, и подменить модуль.

Comment: это только начальная инициализация же? может сразу в файл настроек вставить начальное значение?

Comment: @dgzargo: Не, наоборот, это не инициализация. Это определение того, что у нас первый пробег, и сброс этого самого флага, чотбы в следующий раз уже пробег не считался первым.

Comment: упс, извини! в примерах было много подобного кода только для инициализации